# Failed to resolve libraries: Android Studio 2.2.3

Tags: android, android-studio, android-library

I am getting the following errors and the gradle build fails:

```
Failed to resolve: com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+
Failed to resolve: de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.3.0
Failed to resolve: com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1
```

I have looked thorough almost all the solutions present on stackoverflow but nothing seems to work for me.

```
dependencies {

 compile 'com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1'
 compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'
 compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.3.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
  compileSdkVersion 23
  buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"
}
```

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: can anyone help? I am stuck badly in this.

Answer (score 0):

In project of android studio -> Open Module Settings -> tab dependency -> add item -> find valid version of library

Comment: @ user2930077 Where exactly am I suppose to find the Module Settings in Studio?

Comment: Context menu of project, it located there or press F12